# In a = +a || 0, what does the '+' after '=' do?

Tags: javascript

for example in the `indexOf` polyfill in MDN

```
fromIndex = +fromIndex || 0;
```

What does the  `+` in front of `fromIndex` do?

Comment: FWIW, the operator is [Unary Plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converts it into a number. It's the opposite of `-fromIndex`, so it has to convert into a number.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#-_.28Unary_Plus.29

```
+"0" 
>> 0
+true 
>> 1
```